# Where do I download javacomm for linux now that Oracle decommissioned Suns download site?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, sun

I cannot for the life of me figure out where exactly I can download the javacomm library.

There is a download link on this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html that takes me to a page that states:

> The Sun Download Center was decommissioned on July 31, 2011. 
>   Customers looking for Sun downloads should visit one of the following
>   Oracle websites:
>
> Oracle E-Delivery (https://edelivery.oracle.com) for downloading
>   separately licensed software products Oracle Technology Network
>   (http://otn.oracle.com) for downloading  software for development My
>   Oracle Support (https://support.oracle.com) for downloading hardware
>   related downloads and software product patches and updates

None of those sites seem to have it...

Answer (score 5):

I found the win32 and linux version here http://www.xpl4java.org/xPL4Java/javacomm.html

Comment: Don't understand why the question has more votes than this answer. +1 thanks.

Comment: The link leads to a 404 as of today 2020-12-04